# How to loop MMS video stream from VLC

Tags: vlc-media-player, video-streaming, mms-streaming

I have a VLM config for a mosaic broadcast however once the stream has finished playing, it will not restart regardless of the `loop` option. Does the `loop` option apply to certain streams only or just playlists?

```
# VLC media player VLM command batch
# http://www.videolan.org/vlc/

new bg broadcast enabled loop
setup bg input "fake://"
setup bg output #bridge-in{offset=10}:display
setup bg option fake-file=http://www.allbestwallpapers.com/wallpaper/nature/image/waterfall,_letchworth_state_park,_new_york.jpg
setup bg option fake-width=1024
setup bg option fake-height=768
setup bg option fake-aspect-ratio=16:9
setup bg option sub-filter=mosaic
setup bg option no-mouse-events
setup bg option no-keyboard-events
setup bg option no-audio
setup bg option vout=sdl
setup bg option mosaic-alpha=255
setup bg option mosaic-height=768
setup bg option mosaic-width=1024
setup bg option mosaic-align=5
setup bg option mosaic-xoffset=0
setup bg option mosaic-yoffset=0
setup bg option mosaic-vborder=5
setup bg option mosaic-hborder=5
setup bg option mosaic-bridge-chroma=I420
setup bg option mosaic-position=1
setup bg option mosaic-rows=2
setup bg option mosaic-cols=2
setup bg option mosaic-order=v1,v2,v3,v4
setup bg option no-mosaic-keep-picture
setup bg option no-mosaic-keep-aspect-ratio
new v1 broadcast enabled loop
setup v1 input "mmsh://mediaserver2.otn.ca/mediasite/02c708f2-edf4-4516-bd32-fd2820d22543.wmv"
setup v1 output #mosaic-bridge{id=v1,width=635,height=355}
setup v1 option mms-caching=5000
new v2 broadcast enabled loop
setup v2 input "mmsh://mediaserver2.otn.ca/mediasite/297fe7b7-4764-41e7-b27f-9359ba3a7676.wmv"
setup v2 output #mosaic-bridge{id=v2,width=635,height=355}
setup v2 option mms-caching=5000
new v3 broadcast enabled loop
setup v3 input "mmsh://mediaserver2.otn.ca/mediasite/498e1938-c1a8-405e-8578-57dcf924bec0.wmv"
setup v3 output #mosaic-bridge{id=v3,width=635,height=355}
setup v3 option mms-caching=5000
new v4 broadcast enabled loop
setup v4 input "mmsh://mediaserver2.otn.ca/mediasite/66da9337-9dd3-44ac-99bc-8c79dcb18eed.wmv"
setup v4 output #mosaic-bridge{id=v4,width=635,height=355}
setup v4 option mms-caching=5000


control bg play
control v1 play
control v2 play
control v3 play
control v4 play
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `loop`, try using:

```
setup your_stream option input-repeat=-1
```

Found on the [VideoLan forum](http://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=26340).